# Running Stored Procedure From JMeter

Tags: oracle, jdbc, automation, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a stored procedure as below which I run to create some test data automatically using PL/SQL Developer. It just runs fine.

```
begin
  create_test_data('000000316F1422C8','N',1,'2016-01-26');
end;
/
```

I was automating some project in JMETER and there as part of setup I need to create this data. I tried to connect to Oracle DB using JDBC Request Sampler can fire Select Queries which are working fine.

Now I want to run this Stored Procedure to Generate the data from JMETER: I tried to use JDBC Request sampler and copied the above code but it doesn't work.

Can somebody please help?

1. Is JDBC Request Sampler Correct way to run this Stored procedure
2. While I am running it from JDBC Request Sampler I am getting below Errors:

a. Error 1

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
```

b. Error 2 If I remove slash from the last line

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'CREATE_NEXNET_TEST_DATA' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

3. How can we verify in the end if stored procedure can run successfully

Many Thanks!!

Comment: This is not how you call stored procedures in JDBC. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html Hint: use `{call create_test_data('000000316F1422C8','N',1,'2016-01-26')}`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JMeter is capable of invoking stored procedures, Use `Callable Statement` as "Query Type" and provide relevant Parameter values and types.

References:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54048
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel,

Tried it like below:
begin
{call create_test_data('000000316F1422C8','N',1,'2016-01-28')};
end;

However it gives below error:

ORA-06550: line 2, column 68:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock

Comment: Below Link has no example for stored procedure.

https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter

Comment: begin  
    {call create_test_data('000000316F1422C8','N',1,'2016-01-28')};  
    end;  

Have tried to run the stored procedure like this but it still gives error.  

@MarkRotteveel

Comment: ORA-06550: line 2, column 68:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge

@DmitriT

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks all for help. I have managed to solve this and am able to run stored procedure from JDBC now.

Below is what I used in my Query. Note that Query Type was "Callable Statement"

    begin
    {CALL create_nexnet_test_data(?, ?, ?, ?)}
    end;

Also, used below values:

Parameter Values - xxx, yyy, 123, uuu
Parameter Types - Varchar, Varchar, integer, Varchar
Variable Names - BCSIG, CNOTE, UTYPE, DTAP
Result Variable Name: result

Answer (score 0):

Here this worked fine to me `(without "{", "}", "begin", "end"):`

**Using query type**: Callable Statement

```
CALL SCHEMA_NAME.PKG_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME
     (
          PARAM_1 => 'TESTING',
          PARAM_2 => 0000,
          ...
      )
```